# Why is my authentication not allowing me to log in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to figure out why authenication isn't working properly for my code even with gem devise. My login page displays properly but when it comes to logging in with an existing user's info located in the seeds.rb file, it prints out the else statement instead of directing to the home page.

```
def sign_in
        page = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
        if page.present? && page.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = page.id
            redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have successfully logged in"
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Invalid info"
            redirect_to login_path
        end
    end
```

I changed the user.authenicate(params[:password]) to page.authenicate(params[:password]) but the same issue was still showing.

Started POST "/login" for ::1 at 2022-11-15 19:30:14 -0600
Processing by PagesController#sign_in as TURBO_STREAM
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"email"=>"hi@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:14:in `sign_in'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Completed 302 Found in 188ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 8011)

Started GET "/login" for ::1 at 2022-11-15 19:30:14 -0600
Processing by PagesController#login as TURBO_STREAM
Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
Rendering pages/login.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered pages/login.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.2ms | Allocations: 817)
Rendered shared/_flash.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 31)
Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 80.3ms | Allocations: 6806)
Completed 200 OK in 102ms (Views: 82.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 7152)

Comment: Please go to your rails web server console and post any relevant info. You should see the submit happen in the console. Edit your question and add the output from the beginning of the submit to the where it starts to load the redirect_to.

Comment: And this might sound obvious, but have you seeded your DB? If your seed.rb file has users in it before you create the DB for the first time it will seed the DB. If you created the app and the DB then added  to the seed file you need to run `rails db:seed`.

Comment: Already ran the rails db:seed command but the issue is still there

Comment: If you're gonna reinvent the authentication wheel at least put it in its own controller instead of a garbage drawer "PagesController". Its a pretty damn important part of an application. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual-articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design#single-responsibility-principle

Answer (score 3):

This is the first clue from your log...

`SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL`

params[:email] is null, because the email parameter is in a form called `session`, which you can see in the log...

`"session"=>{"email"=>"hi@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}`

so your code needs to use form name to access the *email* and *password* parameters properly...

```
def sign_in
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email])
  if user.present? && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have successfully logged in"
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Invalid info"
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, are strong params being used? They didn't post the controller code so I'm not sure.

Comment: OP may want to check out https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/Troubleshooting-Rails-7-and-Turbo-Drive since accessing the params goes around any strong params being used in the controller and may be a security concern.

Comment: @Beartech what are you going on about? Devise isn't being used here and there is no mass assignment vulnerability since there is no mass assignement actually being performed. Strong parameters are not going to do anything here - its not a magic wand that makes your params "secure". The more real security concern is reinventing the authentication wheel...

Comment: @max - according to the question the OP is using devise